# How to copy files along with a part of folder structure in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I want to copy all the files from a folder which is more than x days old to a new path.

Source folder structure:

```
/opt/install/sw1/team/p2.csv
/opt/install/sw2/team/p2.csv
```

Destination should be:

```
/work/backup/sw1/team/p2.csv
/work/backup/sw2/team/p2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this do:

```
mkdir /work/backup/sw1/team
find /opt/install/sw1/team -maxdepth 0 -mtime +5 -exec cp '{}' /work/backup/sw1/team \;
mkdir /work/backup/sw2/team
find /opt/install/sw2/team -maxdepth 0 -mtime +5 -exec cp '{}' /work/backup/sw2/team \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
cp -a /opt/install/sw1 /opt/install/sw2
```

Or for verbose:

```
cp -av /opt/install/sw1 /opt/install/sw2
```

`-a` says to copy everything and preserve permissions. If this is not what you want, then `-r` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, missed the required: "more than x days old".